# Assigning List Values to Pandas df Column generates NaN or Length Error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame

```
           Close    Delta   
Date            
2020-05-11  2920.50 -440    
2020-05-11  2920.25 -9      
2020-05-11  2920.25 -27     
2020-05-11  2920.50 2       
2020-05-11  2920.75 117
```

Now i'm calculating consecutive increments of 'Close' with this function:

```
tickbox = []
cumtickCount = 0

for i in range(len(df.index)):
        if df.Close[i] > df.Close[i-1]:
            cumtickCount += 1
            tickbox.append(cumtickCount)
        else:
            cumtickCount = 0
```

I get the list but here I also don't understand why the values starting with 1 and not with 0
tickbox:

```
[1,
 1,
 2,
 3,
 1,
 2,
 3,
 4,
 5,
 6,
 1,
 1,
 2,
 3,
 4,
 5,
 6,
 7,
 8,
 9,
 1,
 2,
 3,
 4,
 5,
```

If I convert the List to the df column

```
ct = pd.Series(tickbox)
df['consec_tick'] = ct
```

I get NaN values

```
            Close   Delta  consec_tick
Date            
2020-05-11  2920.50 -440    NaN
2020-05-11  2920.25 -9      NaN
2020-05-11  2920.25 -27     NaN
2020-05-11  2920.50 2       NaN
2020-05-11  2920.75 117     NaN
```

If I assign the list like this:

```
df.assign(new_col=consec_tickup)
```

or

```
df['consec_tick'] = consec_tickup
```

I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-9d3e9ad7ceb3> in <module>
      7             cumtickCount += 1
      8             #tickbox.append(cumtickCount)
----> 9             df['consec_tick'] = tickbox
     10         else:
     11             cumtickCount = 0

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
   3470         else:
   3471             # set column
-> 3472             self._set_item(key, value)
   3473 
   3474     def _setitem_slice(self, key, value):

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _set_item(self, key, value)
   3547 
   3548         self._ensure_valid_index(value)
-> 3549         value = self._sanitize_column(key, value)
   3550         NDFrame._set_item(self, key, value)
   3551 

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _sanitize_column(self, key, value, broadcast)
   3732 
   3733             # turn me into an ndarray
-> 3734             value = sanitize_index(value, self.index, copy=False)
   3735             if not isinstance(value, (np.ndarray, Index)):
   3736                 if isinstance(value, list) and len(value) > 0:

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py in sanitize_index(data, index, copy)
    610 
    611     if len(data) != len(index):
--> 612         raise ValueError("Length of values does not match length of index")
    613 
    614     if isinstance(data, ABCIndexClass) and not copy:

ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

How can I assign the values from 'tickbox' to the column correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your solution that might stem from my misunderstanding of your goals.

If you want the column to have the same number of values as the other column, you will want to add a value to `tickbox` for EVERY element. In your case, you're not appending anything in the `else` branch, meaning that you're actually skipping some values.

Another issue is that the first value needs to probably be set to `0`. Instead, when `i = 0`, you're comparing element `0` with element `-1`. I actually get a `KeyError: -1` when I try your code.

Taking the above issues into account, we could rewrite the function:

```py
def consecutive_ticks(close_prices):
  # start with 0 for the first data point
  ticks = [0]
  count = 0

  # go from element 1 to the last element
  for i in range(1, len(close_prices)):
    if close_prices[i] > close_prices[i-1]:
      count += 1
    else:
      count = 0
    # we append the current count anyway.
    # it's either going to be an increment, or it's 0 if "close" is smaller
    ticks.append(count)

  return ticks
```

This will return a list with same length as the `close_prices` series. Thus, you can add it to your data frame simply by:

```py
df['consec_tick'] = consecutive_ticks(df.Close)
```